# Does Importing(require) module in JS also executes whole code as well?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export

let moduleFile.js as

```js
const calc = {
    add(a,b) = {return a+b},
    sub(a,b) = {return a-b}
}

console.log(`hello from module`);

exports.calcModule = calc;
```

and let main.js which is in same dir with moduleFile.js as

```js
const { calcModule } = require(`./moduleFile`);

console.log(calcModule.add(1,2));
```

when i execute `main.js` as `$ node main.js` in console
result would be like

```
hello from module
3
```

its hard for me to understand that `hello from module` also printed.
does importing a module includes executing whole module file?

Comment: `does importing a module includes executing whole module file?` Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  The first time a CommonJS module is loaded with `require()`, any top level code is executed.  As you can see, this has to be the case so that `exports.calcModule = calc` runs and establishes the exports for the module and your `console.log('hellow from module')` would also run.

Once loaded, the module is cached so any other calls to `require()` for that same module will just return the export object from the original execution of the module and the top level code will not run again.  So, the top level code only runs once, no matter how many times the module is loaded within your program.

> does importing a module includes executing whole module file?

Yes, it executes all top level code in the module you are loading.

Comment: how become no one points out this import one?!   
thx for reply :)